# Kotlin Adapter OnMapReady get position

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-mapview

I want to get Recycler View Position onMapReady Method. But it seems there are no callback methods for that. In java, I can do this with getAdapterPosition() but it's not working in Kotlin.

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        //val location: Location = locations.get(getAdapterPosition()) // getAdapterPosition not working
        println("onMapReady")
        val sydney = LatLng(31.5204, 74.3587)
        googleMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Sydney"))
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,13.5f));
    }
```

MapView is working fine and the marker is also showing on exact place. But now I want to get data from the array of position of recyclerview. How can I get the position in onMapReady using kotlin.

Comment: You can add new marker when recycler view item clicked with callback, for the first run, you can get desired position from list

Comment: Each card in recyclerview have a mapview with marker. I don't want click item in my view. It should be automatic

Comment: Any solutions yet